# Vertica JDBC wrong

Tags: java, jdbc, vertica

My SQL Query doesn't have any "est" in it. I can use this SQL successfully insert into vertica directly, but it goes wrong when I use JDBC.

> java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at
>   or near "est" [ insert into .... ]
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax
>   error at or near "est"
>       at com.vertica.util.ServerErrorData.buildException(Unknown Source)
>       at com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepareImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepareBatch(Unknown Source)
>       at com.vertica.dataengine.VDataEngine.prepareBatch(Unknown Source)
>       at com.vertica.jdbc.SStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lina.common.util.JdbcConn.executeBatchUpdate(JdbcConn.java:77)

The error with the entire query:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at
>   or near "est" [ insert into public.gamelive_original(hour, minute, ip,
>   country, sp, act, time, uid, pcode, r_name, r_owner, r_owne_id,
>   r_category, online_num, ver,sender,msg,dt) values (
>   '21','40','125.90.93.219','hello',NULL,'webzb',NULL,'10240','hello','hello','hel‌​lo',NULL,'hello','6094',NULL,'yeschenshu','love','2016-01-17'
>   ) ]

Comment: Could you please post the SQL leading to this error?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "est" [ insert into public.gamelive_original(hour, minute, ip, country, sp, act, time, uid, pcode, r_name, r_owner, r_owne_id, r_category, online_num, ver,sender,msg,dt) values ( '21','40','125.90.93.219','hello',NULL,'webzb',NULL,'10240','hello','hello','hello',NULL,'hello','6094',NULL,'yeschenshu','love','2016-01-17' ) ]

Comment: Formatting and added the code from the comment to to question.

Comment: Could you please share target table DDL?

Comment: It probably does, you just don't see it. What is generating the statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stacktrace indicates a **batched** update - error will be in one of the updated rows.

As your log shows parameters inside SQL you probably didn't use `PreparedStatement`

My best guess: you have missing escaping in your code and insert a string like...

```
  "C'est la vie"
```

Which without proper escaping will create a Sql like

```
  insert into foo(bar) values('C'est la vie')
```

Which would create an error *near "est"*